# Lazy call to PHP script for use as tooltip contents

Tags: javascript, php, tooltip

I'm trying to figure out what would be the shortest and simplest way to lazily load tooltips with PHP-generated contents inside. I've found a pretty solid library called PowerTip which I've been trying to appropriate however there are some difficulties there.

So I'm going to have a block of text and positioning a cursor over any word longer than three characters in that text should invoke a PHP script passing that word as a parameter, reading the response which is plain html and passing it inside the tooltip contents. When a user hovers over some word they'd get a nicely formatted tooltip which is specifically related to that word.

I'm looking to have a clean and easily maintainable HTML code that allows me to have as little javascript in different places as possible and preferably without duplicating the text's contents elsewhere and the tooltip should look good (not just a regular  kind of a tooltip) and follow cursor. What would be the best way to approach this problem?

PHP script is already done, I'm looking to solve the javascript/interaction problem.

Comment: You have to show us some code first ,how much you have tried etc

Comment: Well, I haven't tried much except trying to play with PowerTip's library example file trying to appropriate it for my needs. I'm not sure it's the right way to go though so first of all I'm asking advice on the general direction rather than looking for a working solution right away.

Comment: so the block of text you are talking about , may be you can parse every new word(or line or para ) before you add the word to this block , add tooltip to the word if its greater than three alphabet and that's it. How you add the tooltip depends on you but I think this would be a good way to go

Comment: Yeah, that actually sounds like a good idea. Alright, but that was one of the obstacles that I couldn't surmount due to my limited knowledge of Javascript. There are two parts to it: with PowerTip I cannot lazy-load links because I'd have to have a separate line in a script for each word. Second is that I couldn't figure out how to turn a string if (!$(this).data('powertip')) {      $(this).data('powertip', 'Tooltip added: ' + (new Date())).powerTip({manual: true}); into something that sends a request ($.get) and receives data: the (new Date())) part is supposed to perform that.

Comment: The way I see it though is that we have a text, each needed word is framed like so <span class="lookup">apple</span>, and we basically see in javascript that if an element has that class then (on mouseover) we need to get the contents from within it, pass it to a script and generate our tooltip on the fly with the contents of the response. Will that be hard to accomplish?

Comment: yeah seems okie I wil try it and get back to it ,you should try it too